# Check in xcode 6 when webserver makes a http post?

Tags: swift, web, uiwebview, xcode6

I'm using xcode 6 to make an app which have to communicate with my web application. I'm using UIWEBVIEW to show my web in the app. Is there a way i can check in the app when the web makes a http post.

Comment: this may sound hard, but you can do http post to your native code (swift, objective c) and make the native code to bridge the post request

Comment: I have search and search and there is no example or anything which can lead me to a solution - im totally lost...